# strptime does not convert certain dates

Tags: r, strptime, posixlt

I try to convert three dates from `character` to `strptime`

Using `times1`

```
times1 <- c("26/Mar/2015 12:47:27", "28/Mar/2015 13:15:59", "31/Mar/2015 10:05:26")

# times1
# >[1] "26/Mar/2015 12:47:27" "28/Mar/2015 13:15:59" "31/Mar/2015 10:05:26"

# conversion
times1 <- strptime(times1, "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# times1
# > [1] NA NA
```

all the dates are `NA` after the conversion.

Choosing other dates in  `times2`

```
times2 <- c("17/Apr/2015 22:17:42", "24/Apr/2015 00:04:56")

# times2
# > [1] "17/Apr/2015 22:17:42" "24/Apr/2015 00:04:56"

# conversion
times2 <- strptime(times2, "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# times2
# > [1] "2015-04-17 22:17:42 CEST" "2015-04-24 00:04:56 CEST"
```

I can convert them without a problem.

Both converted variables are of the class `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`.

I think it is not a summer-/wintertime issue. I am in Germany (Berlin time), in case it matters.

Comment: It is like this: `[1] "2015-03-26 12:47:27 CET"  "2015-03-28 13:15:59 CET" 
[3] "2015-03-31 10:05:26 CEST"`

Comment: Probably locale dependent. See `?strptime`. `%b`: Abbreviated month name in the **current locale on this platform**. Several posts on this topic on SO.

Comment: http://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months.htm

Comment: Take a look into `?strptime`, it is documented in the examples. In other words, something along these lines `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`

Comment: @BenBolker nice find, probably could close

Comment: @rmuc8: yes.  Did you see the web link I posted?

Comment: @David Arenburg Thank you